# Prove that the function $f:G \to G$ given by $f(a)=a^k$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be abelian group of order $n$ and let $k$ be a positive integer.If $(k,n)=1$, Prove that the function $f:G \to G$ given by $f(a)=a^k$ is an isomorphism.

My attempt:

let $a, b \in G$ then $f(ab)=(ab)^k=a^kb^k=f(a)f(b)$

so $f$ is homo
Is i am correct how to prove one-one and onto

Comment: If it's an abelian group, why is there both a multiplication and an addition? Did you mean to have a commutative ring?

Comment: @Hayden..sorry sir i have a question  if this abliean we need to show with respect multiplication?

Comment: If $G$ is an arbitrary abelian group then how is your additive statement relevant? To show that your map is a group homomorphism, you only need to demonstrate that the operation holds through the map. As in, you need only show $f(ab) = f(a)f(b).$

Comment: Since $(n,k)=1$ there are $a,b$ such that $an+bk=1$. If $r$ is such that $e=f(r)=r^k$. Therefore $r=r^{an+bk}=(r^{n})^a(r^k)^b=e^ae^b=e$.

Comment: @treeleaf..what you are trying to showed ..

Comment: @treeleaf..can you give me hint how to prove one-one and onto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a^k=b^k \Rightarrow (ab^{-1})^k= 1$ but $gcd(k,n)=1$ therefore $n $ does not divide $k$. So $k=1 \Rightarrow a=b.$ Now there exists x and y such that $kx+ny=1 x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, so for any $b\in G$ we have $ (b^{x})^k =b$ as $|x|$ does not divide $n$ we have $b^{x} \neq 1$ . Thus proved.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe nice to know, the opposite direction is also true: if $G$ is an abelian group of order $n$, $k$ an integer and $f: a \mapsto a^k$ is an isomorphism, then gcd$(k,n)=1$. Proof: assume gcd$(k,n)\neq 1$. Then we can find a prime $p$ with $p \mid k$ and $p \mid n$. By Cauchy's Theorem there is an $a \in G$ with order$(a)=p$. Then $a^k=a^{p \cdot \frac{k}{p}}=1^\frac{k}{p}=1$. Since $f$ is injective this yields $a=1$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The proof that $f$ is a homomorphism is correct.

Suppose $a\in\ker f$, that is, $a^k=1$. Write $1=kx+ny$ (Bézout), so
$$
a=a^1=a^{kx+ny}=(a^k)^x(a^n)^y=1
$$
because it's a general fact that $a^n=1$, for every $a$ in a group of order $n$.

Thus $\ker f=\{1\}$ and $f$ is injective. Do you need anything else? (Hint: no.)

> Since $G$ is finite, $f$ is also surjective.